# Is adding custom method to javascript document object considered to be bad

Tags: javascript, html, performance, dom

I know to select by using attribute you can use querySelectorAll and pass attributes inside []. However, that's not my question. For example, I have a custom method like

```
function getElementsByAttribute(attribute){
  var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*'), 
      elm,
      found=[];
      for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++)
      {
          elm = allElements[i];
          if (elm.getAttribute(attribute))
          {
              found.push(elm);
          }
      }
      return found;
  }
```

If I want to add this to the document object by

```
document.getElementsByAttribute = getElementsByAttribute
```

Is this considered as a bad practice? If it is bad, then what would be a good practice?

Comment: What's the point of adding it?

Comment: If you're targeting modern browsers that support `document.querySelector`/`document.querySelectorAll`, there's no reason to have a function like this.

Comment: @DaveNewton this could be faster than querySelectorAll. However, i am just exploring stuff in javaScript and became curious

Comment: why would you want to type more? there is little/nothing to be gained from this.

Comment: http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/

Comment: @JaredFarrish this is just an example and i know about querySelectorAll (mentioned in the question). i am just curious any side effect or performance hit. just exploring JS

Comment: No, your Javascript code is not going to be faster than native functions. This is one reason why you would probably not want to do this. @Bergi's link gives a fairly good round-up of the pitfalls.

Comment: it's just unnecessary.You're not even using `this`in your function,there is no point adding anything to document. Waste of time.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I dont completely agree with "your Javascript code is not going to be faster than native functions". For example, a simple if loop could be faster than build in filter (depends on what you are trying to do). http://jsperf.com/array-filter-vs-simple-loop/2

Comment: I'm not going to argue about technique; if you'd like to rebuild Javascript core functions in Javascript, go for it. There's a reason why Sizzle.js is only used if `document.querySelectorAll` is not supported.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I am just trying to understand and explore.  i am reading the link provided by Bergi's. i appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally considered a Bad Idea™. Modifying the core of the language in any way, while an amazing ability dynamic languages allow, can lead to unexpected behaviors. For example, what would happen if `getElementsByAttribute` became a method in JS proper. Then your method would overwrite it and cause anyone depending on your code to get strange and unexpected behavior rather than the core JS method.

Usually what is recommended is to place your custom methods in a namespace that you own and that won't pollute the core language for other people.

The ever-insightful Addy Osmani has some great ideas on how this can be done: http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/

One such example could look like the following:

```
myExtensions = {
  getElementsByAttribute: function(attribute) { ... }
}
```

which you could then simply call with: `myExtensions.getElementsByAttribute(...)`

If you wanted to make it similar to calling it on document, you could call the namespace `myDocument` instead of `myExtensions` or really whatever you wanted.